# PHPExcel delete rows in a loop

Tags: php, row, phpexcel, xlsx

is there a more efficient way to delete rows in a loop than this workaround?

```
/**
 * Delete all rows that are identified on the 'D' 
 * column with a $tag String value 
 * @param String $tag
 */
protected function deleteRowsByTag( $tag )
{
    $found = true;
    while( $found )
    {
        $found = false;
        foreach ( $this->objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row )
        {
            $cell = $this->objWorksheet->getCell( "D" . $row->getRowIndex() );
            $tag = str_replace( "tag_delete_", "", $tag );
            if ( strtolower( trim( $cell->getValue() ) ) === $tag )
            {
                $delete_row = $row->getRowIndex();
                // $this->objWorksheet->getRowIterator()->seek( $delete_row-2 );
                $this->objWorksheet->removeRow( $delete_row );
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
} // deleteRowByTag
```

I tried setting the row iterator to a prev->prev position but this did not do the trick (one of my attempts is commented in the code)

Thanks

PS: @Mark Baker - I am sorry, I did not read the manual too extensively :)

Comment: There's no clever way of doing this built into PHPExcel itself: however, I'd recommend working backwards from the last row to the first

Comment: If you're simply trying to hide the rows for display purposes (saving as an Excel spreadsheet again) then setting an AutoFilter might be an option

Comment: Your first commend gave me an "aha" moment. Thank you.